# Should the "/dev" directory always be writable?

Tags: permissions, devices, kubernetes

I have noticed that in a read-only kubernetes container, the `/dev` directory is still writable. I was wandering whatever the `/dev` directory should be writable by design? or is it possible to make it also read-only ?

Comment: you'll have to ask the developers of that particular container - for security (i.e. to prevent non-root users from creating, deleting, or changing device nodes), /dev is typically owned by root:root with mode 755 (rwxr-xr-x), but the devs may have had a reason (not necessarily a *good* reason) for changing that.

Comment: @cas
`/dev` is indeed owned by root, the question is - is it mandatory that `dev` will be also *writable* by root? or it's possible to have `dev` which will be read-only ?

Comment: if root can't write to /dev, then how can root create the device nodes (either via udev or manually with mknod)?   root:root/755 are the correct owner:group/perms for /dev

Comment: @cas presumably, that's precisely what the OP is asking. Could you post an answer with some examples to show why root needs to write to `/dev`?

Comment: The interesting angle here is why root would need to write to `/dev` in a container...

Comment: IME containers typically have their own /dev (and /dev/shm too), usually tmpfs for both, not a bind mount to the host's /dev, so they need to be writable at boot at least.  After boot, there's probably no particular reason to go to the trouble of making it RO...and some stuff like /dev/pts/ probably needs to be RW anyway (in case someone needs an interactive shell in the container).  That's just a guess, I can't say anything for sure about this particular container.

Comment: @terdon i'd just be guessing, and guesses don't make for good answers.  it's far too late here to do any research on the topic anyway.

Comment: @cas: In theory you could make it read-only, as most containers only have a static list of devices (which can be pre-created before starting the container – there is no udev in containers, nor does udev create device nodes anymore anyways). /dev/pts is a mounted virtual filesystem, so it's not writable at all; it's /dev/shm that needs to remain writable though.